# Compiler Error Message: BC30205: End of statement expected

Tags: asp.net, compiler-errors, expression-web

What's the problem of this code??

```
Compiler Error Message: BC30205: End of statement expected.

Source Error:

Line 1:  <script runat="server" type="css">
Line 2:  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
Line 3:  {
Line 4:      if (!IsPostBack)
Source File: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\logon\page.aspx    Line: 1
```

Help please ?

Comment: The `type="css"` maybe ?

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your `Page_Load` method, it's going to be hard to tell. Any possibility you can add the rest of the method to your question?

Comment: i already solved it. Thanks for your replies. I just add <%@ Page Language="C#"%> in my code :)

Comment: Is not the `type=css`, but this is for sure not correct. Show us the page header, maybe there you have defind some wrong, or the rest of your code, you have forget to close some parentheses.

Comment: I already solved my problem :)) i just added  <%@ Page Language="C#"%> in my code :) thanks everyone!

Comment: @PetersonPilares Now is better to give an answer to your self here, accept it and move on (do not delete it because is count negative to your image on SO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already solved my problem :)) i just added <%@ Page Language="C#"%> in my code :) thanks everyone!